# Angular5 mat select

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using mat-select material and Angular5. I'm stuck in problem like I'm not able to bind the values to my *ngfor in mat-select.

The values are get from rest API  response and I'm assigning it to value assigned to ngfor in mat select when I console it I'm able to see the values ,but in html I couldn't get the value help me.!

```
html
<mat-select name="name" [(ngModel)]="nameselected">
<mat-optgroup *ngFor="let name of names" [label]="name.SurName">
<mat-option   *ngFor="let hobby of name.hobbies" [value]="hobby.hobbyName" >
      {{ hobby.hobbyName }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>
</mat-select>

component.ts

getNames(){
return this.nameService.getNames().subscribe(data => { this.names = data
console.log(names, this.names);
this.names=this.nameList;});
}
```

Comment: What does you code look like so far?

Comment: have attached the code ..suggest me a solution!

Comment: i found the problem in my code..the response is under data  so                   
    /this.names = data.data/ contains my value...

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is properties in your angular model doesn't match with properties from API data 
try to check name or type of variable again